# Count frequency of list of words in list of string in Python

Tags: python, list, frequency, cpu-word

I am trying to find the frequency of list of words in list.
I do not know to iterate over list of list and getting list of list output.
Here is the code:

```py
vocab = ['another', 'create', 'different', 'example', 'sample', 'ten']

vocabdoc = [
    ['create', 'ten', 'different', 'different', 'sample'],
    ['create', 'ten', 'another', 'another', 'example', 'example', 'example']
]

output = []

for words in vocab:
    output = [item in vocab for item in vocabdoc].count(words)
    print(output)
```

I am trying to get this result:

```py
output = [[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1],[2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `output = [item.count(words) in vocab for item in vocabdoc]`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the specific issue you have.
Providing a specific question will give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Try to do first without list-comprehesion in normal for loops, then go with list-compreheision

```
output = []
for v in vocabdoc:
    output.append([v.count(x) for x in vocab])

print(output)
[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1]]
```